# I'm trying to code solutions for an AS400 using C#, where can I find the cwbx.dll?

Tags: c#, dll, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I have iSeries Access for Windows. I can open the program and such but I don't see any .dlls in the directory. I've done a bit of searching and everyone says that the .dlls should be there when you download iSeries Access for Windows. Am I missing something?

Comment: may be they installed in GAC?

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows 7 computer, the dlls are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Shared`

[image: Screenshot of directory]